# Which password database system work with ansible?

Tags: ansible, passwords

Which password database system work with ansible to manage password of network devices and servers?

Comment: What tools did you find? Did you look into ansible-vault?

Comment: @BOMA: What "password database system" would you like to use?

Comment: Short answer : All password database system with an API

Answer (score 3):

Any system would do. You might need to write a wrapper. For example:

```
> cat get-passwd-01.yml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - command: ~/bin/get-passwd user9
      register: password
    - debug:
        msg: "passwd:{{ password.stdout }}"
```

.

```
> ansible-playbook get-passwd-01.yml | grep msg
    "msg": "passwd: T4gpJtZ69R5cZD9zQh"
```